# Configuration Backup Rollback

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, backup, cumulative-update, patching

We have an on-premise Sharepoint 2013 Standard farm where since applying the September 2015 CU a bug has appeared in In-Place Search - tests on other farms with the same patch level have the same result, and those prior to this patch don't.

I took a configuration-only backup before applying the patch; my question is, if we were to restore this config backup, would it also revert the patch level, or is that held seperatley?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should try the same operation in acceptance test, before moving on to production!

Second, you would have to uninstall the KB on each SharePoint Server as well, since some of the patches are installed on the server itself and not only in the database.

Comment: We don't have a UAT environment for the client, and are unlikely to either get them to pay for one, or have time to build a replica.

Comment: The main question is would the config backup rollback also roll back the patch level, if I also removed any OS-side traces of it as you mentioned?

Comment: Yes. The KB's need to be uninstalled from the SharePoint Server as well. But without UAT I would try to find another solution, since it's a risky project. I've done it on a development environment once, and it wasn't pretty :(

Comment: Yeah I imagine it would probably be less hassle to just raise the patch level... good to know it's possible at least though, thanks for the input.

Comment: As noted in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/george_bethanis/2014/08/28/sharepoint-server-2013-can-you-uninstall-patches/ you cannot uninstall CU patches to SharePoint. There may be some options if the configuration wizard has not been run, but if the wizard has been run and the databases updated, then your only way is forwards...

Comment: If you only have one farm, you have a test farm...not a production farm.